# Is there a way to check debug=true in startup.auth in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I see that we can use HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled in controllers to check if debug=true is enabled in web.config. How can I check the same in startup.auth? I need to set different app Ids for my local and production environments for fb authentication using this condition. Please suggest if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: A better way: put the values in web.config and generate different web.config for each environment. The startup.auth code shouldn't be coded to care about the exact values.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a web.config entry for whatever dynamic data you need to set and then use web.config transforms to change the data depending on environment. This is very commonly used with connection strings to set different source databases depending on what environment youre in (local vs test vs prod).
See the example below:

local Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="myConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Web.Debug.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="myConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myTestSqlServer;Initial Catalog=myTestDb;User Id=myTestUserId;Password=myTestPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Web.Release.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="myConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myProdSqlServer;Initial Catalog=myProdDb;User Id=myProdUserName;Password=myProdPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```